# Algebraic varieties of the form $f(x_1)+\cdots +f(x_n)=c$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Suppose $f(t)\in K(t)$ is a (non-constant) rational function, where $K$ is a field, and $c\in K^*$ is a constant. I am interested on algebraic varieties that have equations of the form
$$ f(x_1)+\cdots + f(x_n) = c$$
(on the affine space where one takes out from $\mathbb A^n$ the hyperplanes $x_i=a$ for any $a$ root of the denominator of $f(t)$, or better its natural projectivization).

**Question:** Do this varieties have a special name, or do you know some general results studying these varieties?

I know that the special case $f(t)=at^n$ (so $f(t)$ is a monomial) are called diagonal hypersurfaces (at least if $n\ge 1$), and there are several papers and even a book by Gouvêa and Yui about them over finite fields.